# Why doesn't Python write directly to a file after each iteration of for loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, io, stream

I wanted to make a simulation of a stream and so I looped through an text file line by line, writing the lines to another text file with a `time.sleep()` of `1` second. The problem is that python doesn't write each line to the file after 1 second but only when it gets to around 260 lines.
I don't think that the lines are the point I think it is more about the size of each line, because with different line size I get different waiting time/size. Does anyone know why python3 behaves like that and how can I solve it?

My code:

```
import io
import time

with io.open('stream.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f, io.open('source.txt', encoding="utf-8") as g:
    for line in g:
        print(line, file=f, end='')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because a file object is actually a stream, so data is not written to the file immediately but in larger chunks of data. Use `io.flush()` to force writing.
See here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush

Comment: Just to update your Answer the flush works like: print (line, file=f, end='', flush=True)